# Error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error when using Sheets in range command

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and have an issue with a command, I've separated it out in to a separate Excel spreadsheet and still can't get it to work.

If I use the following on the active work sheet all is fine

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(99, 2)).Value = "Test"
```

But when I use:

```
Sheets("one").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(99, 2)).Value = "Test"
```

I receive the error `1004 application defined or object defined error`.

I have the sheet named "one" in my workbook.

I spent the last few hours searching through Google, but no luck, can anyone suggest what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have to also qualify the `Cells()` object

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("one")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(99, 2)).Value = "Test"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot how explicit you have to be with VBA.